# ProducerBlockedQuotaExceededError: Cannot create producer on topic with backlog quota exceeded

Tags: java, solr, apache-pulsar, lucidworks

I have a **Lucidworks Fusion 5** *kubernetes* installation setup on **AWS EKS** and currently one of the services, *Connector Classic REST service*, is experiencing an outage. After digging into the logs I found:

```
ERROR in com.lucidworks.logging.logback.PulsarAppender[PULSAR] - Failed to connect to Pulsar topic persistent://uat/_logs/system_logs at: pulsar://uat-pulsar-broker:6650 org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$ProducerBlockedQuotaExceededError: Cannot create producer on topic with backlog quota exceeded
```

From here I took a look at the **pulsar-broker** configmap and found:

```
backlogQuotaDefaultLimitGB: "10"
```

I am not well versed in **Apache Pulsar** but it seems to me that if I try raising this *backlog quota limit* it should allow the  *Connector Classic REST service* to connect to the broker again, which should bring the *Connector Classic REST service* back up. Is that a fair assessment ?

- Without changing any configuration is there a way to resolve this issue (e.g. restarting a particular service, ...) ?
- What is the best way to go about this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue I followed these steps:

1. Shell into the pulsar-broker pod
2. Change directories into the */pulsar/bin* directory
3. Use pulsar-admin CLI to find the subscription that needs to be cleared

   `./pulsar-admin topics subscriptions <topic>`
4. Clear the *backlog* with the following command

   `./pulsar-admin topics clear-backlog <topic> -s <subscription>`
5. Shell out and delete the *Connector Classic REST* pod
6. After a few minutes the service comes back up